# Triple moniter SLI with intel graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

Hello I am putting a Linux distro on my desktop and I have Triple monitors and wanting to run the Intel graphics chips on the 2 side 1080p monitors while my sli runs the center monitor on Ubuntu 15.04.

I have tried many time prior to this and been unsuccessful so had to go back to windows. Please help me If it is impossible with the Intel chips graphics please help with triple monitor SLI.

Dual 760gtx in SLI
4600 HD Intel GPU